# Multiple Dynamic Selects queries in one return

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I need to run multiple select count queries to count how many people are available at certain times through the day to plot into a table from ms sql server.

I have the below sql which works, but is returning each count as a new table, I would like them to all in one table on different columns.

```
DECLARE @Day varchar(max)
SET @Day = 'Sunday' 

DECLARE @Provider varchar(max)
SET @Provider = '58611'


DECLARE @sqlText varchar(max); 

SET @sqlText = N'SELECT COUNT(*) AS Available0700 
  FROM tblCarersRota INNER JOIN tblCarersProviders ON tblCarersProviders.CarerID = tblCarersRota.CarerID
  WHERE Rotation = 2 AND  tblCarersProviders.ProviderID = '''+ @Provider + ''' AND ''07:00'' between ' + @Day + 'StartTime AND ' + @Day + 'EndTime  '
Exec (@sqlText)

SET @sqlText = N'SELECT COUNT(*) AS Available0800 
  FROM tblCarersRota INNER JOIN tblCarersProviders ON tblCarersProviders.CarerID = tblCarersRota.CarerID
  WHERE Rotation = 2 AND  tblCarersProviders.ProviderID = '''+ @Provider + ''' AND ''08:00'' between ' + @Day + 'StartTime AND ' + @Day + 'EndTime  '
Exec (@sqlText)
```

Actual current result:

```
Available0700
21


Available0800
22
```

Desired result:

```
Available0700 || Available0800   
21            || 22
```

I have looked at where you select (select query 1) (select query 2) but I can't get that to work with the dynamic sqltext.

How can I modify my selects to get them to all return as 1 table?

Thanks

Comment: I've tried a union all and that brought back both of the count values in one column called Available0700, it never made the second column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1, put it in 2 rows with `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as Counts, 'Available0700' AvailableTime
FROM ...
UNION all
SELECT COUNT(*) as Counts, 'Available0800' AvailableTime
FROM ...
```

Option 2, in 2 columns with subqueries:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...) as Available0700,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...) as Available0800
```

Comment: I have tried both of those - option 1 is bringing all counts back in one column (see my comment on the question) option 2 I can't get to work as I'm having to use dynamic sql

Comment: @JoshCooper option 1 is designed to show it in 2 rows as specified in the answer. Option 2, you just need to put your dynamic sql in the bracketed subqueries and exec once.

Comment: Thanks for explaining where I went wrong, option 2 works perfectly now

Answer (score 0):

I think you can store these values in variables and finally select these variables in your select query.

Below is an example code in which i have used a table variable to execute the dynamic queries and store the records and finally used a PIVOT query to fetch the require output.

```
DECLARE @tablevar TABLE
(
    Query VARCHAR(100),
    Cnt INT
)
DECLARE @sqlText varchar(max)
SET @sqlText = N'SELECT ''Available Value 1'', 100 '
INSERT INTO @tablevar
Exec (@sqlText)


SET @sqlText = N'SELECT ''Available Value 2'', 200 '
INSERT INTO @tablevar
Exec (@sqlText)


SET @sqlText = N'SELECT ''Available Value 3'', 300 '
INSERT INTO @tablevar
Exec (@sqlText)

SELECT * FROM @tablevar 
PIVOT(SUM(Cnt) FOR Query IN([Available Value 1], [Available Value 2], [Available Value 3])) AS PIV
```

Above code is an example, please replace it with your actual code accordingly.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why did you use dynamic query? You can use case when inside operator COUNT in such way: `COUNT(CASE WHEN <yours filter with time 7.00 > then 1 else null end)  AS Available0700 , COUNT(CASE WHEN <yours filter with time 8.00 > then 1 else null end)  AS Available0800`.

Comment: I used dynamic so I can use the variable day to specify the column of today. E.g. today it would pass Thursday and place it so 'day'booked column would be ThursdayBooked

Comment: So, you can do something like that 
``SET @sqlText = N'SELECT 
COUNT(CASE WHEN ''07:00'' between ' + @Day + 'StartTime AND ' + @Day + 'EndTime  ' then 1 else null end) AS Available0700 ,
COUNT(CASE WHEN ''08:00'' between ' + @Day + 'StartTime AND ' + @Day + 'EndTime  ' then 1 else null end) AS Available0800
  FROM tblCarersRota INNER JOIN tblCarersProviders ON tblCarersProviders.CarerID = tblCarersRota.CarerID
  WHERE Rotation = 2 AND  tblCarersProviders.ProviderID = '''+ @Provider + ''' 
Exec (@sqlText)``